# Go-Git custom push options

Tags: go, go-git

I want to push to gitlab from a go program. I'm using [go-git](https://github.com/go-git/go-git) v5 for it. The standard push is working fine:

```
err := repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
            RefSpecs: []config.RefSpec{"refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"},
            Progress: os.Stdout,
        })
```

Now I want to add a custom gitlab push option "ci.skip".

The git command would be `git push -o ci.skip`. I tried adding Options like this:

```
err := repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        RefSpecs: []config.RefSpec{"refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"},
        Progress: os.Stdout,
        Options: map[string]string{"ci.skip":"true"},
    })
```

but the compiler tells me

`p.Options undefined (type *git.PushOptions has no field or method Options)`

I don't really get it as the [PushOptions](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/32c4f532abd57797322e97d95dfa02821980e309/options.go#L196) struct clearly has this property. I'm pretty new to Go, so I probably miss some concept here.

Comment: `PushOptions` is new after version 5.4.2, i.e., it's not in any *release* version. See commit `e729edb00d36e9bd19f99dfa493984233b0dccfa`, added 26 Oct 2021.

Comment: Wow, not released yet. Thanks for the hint. If you write an answer instead of a comment I'll accept it ;).